# Is it possible to feed csv input in the Tensorflow Playground?

Tags: javascript, python, typescript

There are different functions and the data required definition varies.
I have gone through the `dataset.ts` file which can be viewed here: [dataset.ts](https://github.com/tensorflow/playground/blob/master/src/dataset.ts)
I have tried to manipulate the file for example like this:

```
export function classifyTwoGaussData(numSamples: number, noise: number):
    Example2D[] {
  let points: Example2D[] = [];

  let varianceScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, .5]).range([0.5, 4]);
  let variance = varianceScale(noise);

  function genGauss(cx: number, cy: number, label: number) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numSamples / 2; i++) {
      let x = normalRandom(cx, variance);
      let y = normalRandom(cy, variance);
      points.push({x, y, label});
    }
  }

  genGauss(2, 2, 1); // Gaussian with positive examples.
  genGauss(-2, -2, -1); // Gaussian with negative examples.
  console.log(points);
  return points;
}
```

The output in the console window show: `Array(200)` and when I have added the single line `genGauss(-2, 2, 0);` then I got `Array(300)`.

But I cannot understand if I have a csv full of inputs and a single out, how I can set it inside the playground dataset so that I can visualize the training of my tensorflow model.

The sample data is something like the following:

```
input1  input2  input3  input4  input5  input6  input7  output
1.20047 1.20047 1.20045 1.20045 1.200059606178815   0.0003585714285714223   -3.791789292925229e-06  -1.0
1.20088 1.20088 1.20087 1.20087 1.200329737452543   0.0003835714285714117   6.180045764568489e-07   -1.0
1.20007 1.20023 1.20007 1.20007 1.200243158301695   0.0004278571428571306   4.129903631236368e-06   0.0
1.20022 1.20023 1.20022 1.20023 1.2002387722011298  0.0004271428571428402   7.19294850670973e-06    1.0
1.20023 1.20029 1.20023 1.20029 1.2002558481340868  0.0004192857142857093   9.916424565845627e-06   1.0
1.20046 1.20046 1.20046 1.20046 1.2003238987560578  0.00042499999999998485  1.259884292315837e-05   0.0
1.20053 1.20053 1.20053 1.20053 1.2003925991707052  0.0004049999999999966   1.523257396764079e-05   0.0
```

Kindly, suggest and help me. I am quite in a dilemma as there is no answer from the tensorflow team nor even they care if someone is asking queries to them related to their own product.

Comment: Why not use tensorflowJs to implement your neural network and use a visual tool to display the output?

Comment: @edkeveked Sorry but what do you mean? I didn't understood your point

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would like to use your csv file in the tensorboard of tensorflow, is it not the reason why you use the Python tag? If that's the case, you could try to use the JavaScript API of tensorflow

Comment: Actually my intention is to load the csv and display it on the Playground of Tensorflow. But that is later part. Currently I need to load the csv. Thats it.

Comment: Maybe you can use the open source code on github: https://github.com/tensorflow/playground/blob/master/README.md to achieve what you want

Comment: @edkeveked The code what I am using itself is from the tensorflow playground. I am trying to add my csv to that code. But not understanding the issue with it.